# Generate Inputs for list of object using tag helper or html helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Here is my model **Movie**

```
class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public List<Actor> Cast { get; set; }
    public List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

And this is **Country** Model

```
public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I send a request to some Api and populate movie object then send it directly to  the view *CreateMovie*. *CreateMovie* view has a form that is filled with movie data.

**Problem**: I need to encapsulate the logic of creating inputs for collection types like countries property into a tag helper or html helper.

How Can I Turn this code into a tag helper or html helper ?

```
@if(Model.Countries != null && Model.Countries.Any())
{
    for (var index = 0; index < Model.Countries.Count; index++)
    {
        <div>
            <label asp-for="@Model.Countries[index].Name"></label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.Countries[index].Name"/>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Right now, I'm using this code to encapsulate the logic into a html helper

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlContent EditorFor<T>(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, List<T> source, string listName, string listItemProperty)

    {
        if (source != null && source.Any())
        {
            var property = typeof(T).GetProperties().Single(p => p.Name == listItemProperty);
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
            {
                var content =
                    $"<input name=\"{listName}[{i}].{listItemProperty}\" value=\"{property.GetValue(source[i])}\" type=\"text\" />";

                result.Append(content);
            }

            return new HtmlString(result.ToString());
        }
        return new HtmlString("");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain why your current attempt is not working.

Comment: @StephenMuecke my current solution is working. but i have a lot of properties that are collection of complex object like "country". I'm trying to create generic and strongly typed method to encapsulate the logic so I can use it for others views and keep my views cleaned.

Comment: Sorry, to be harsh, but you code shows no understanding of how to create a `HtmlHelper` extension method, and why they are used. Its not really clear what you want to achieve with this (your just creating one input for one property of the collection). I suggest you first start by studying the source code for the existing `HtmlHelper` methods.

Comment: If your trying to generate a tabular layout of your collection properties for display and/or editing, you might be interested in [this plugin](https://github.com/stephenmuecke/mvc-tablehelper). I have not added any documentation yet although I did write [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/774228/MVC-Html-Table-Helper-Part-Display-Tables) on the `@Html.TableDisplayFor()` method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your response. It's almost what I needed.